# React Native caching vs application state

Tags: react-native

I have to choose the best multilingual react native app. One performs with application state and the other gets results with caching which I'm not sure is possible.
Which one gives the best performance to save language data. Should I save it in state or in a cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can create multilingual app, in react-native, there is an [async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) which is supported by the react-native community. Through async-storage, you can detect and switch the language of the app.

In order to use state, for that, you would need a persistent redux store to check the state of the app and switch your app language.

I would recommend you to go through to the below article

[Multilingual app in react-native and redux](https://medium.com/@damienmason/multilingual-react-native-app-with-redux-4fc099bb3e4b)
[Multilingual app react-native with async-storage](https://medium.com/codespace69/reactnative-how-to-change-language-of-my-app-in-run-time-when-user-selects-the-language-2e75bd134119)

Comment: For the multilingual app, async-storage is fast if you use with react-native-i18n